# Unable to create XLS file on web server

Tags: wcf, office-interop

We have a WCF application on our web server. One of the service methods in this app creates an Excel XLS file with data and places the file in a directory so the user can down load the file later.

Our problem is that when this app attempts to create the Excel object, we get this error: Error in Create Excel Helper Workbook, and Application: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
failed due to the following error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password.

This is the line that causes the error:

using EX = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
EX.Application Application = new EX.Application();  //causes error

I did some research and what I have tried is to go into DCOMCNFG - Computers - My Computer - DCOM Config and Right clicked "Microsoft Excel previewer" - properties - Security, then added several groups and users to have Local Launch, Local Activation, etc....

But this did not help. Some of the articles say to choose "Microsoft Excel Application". However, I only see "Microsoft Excel previewer" in my DCOM Config.

Excel is installed on this server but we still have the above problem.

One strange thing is that if I remote into the server, then have my client(browser) on my PC call the service method to create the XLS, this works without a problem.

What do I have to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you check the iis pool user's properties, about load full profile, etc?

Comment: I changed the App Pool 'Load User Profile' to True, it was False. Restarted App Pool, but we still get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attempt to make this work by setting the IIS AppPool Identity to a user that has interactive logon rights.  The interop assemblies actually work by launching an Excel instance on the server and then communicating with it to perform work.

That being said, having gone down this road before, it is a poor solution.  The challenges you'll face are as follows:

- Issues with DCOM permissions that are difficult to diagnose and resolve (you're running into this now)
- Excel processes get spawned on the server and half the time do not close properly, so your application has to be smart enough to go around killing errant Excel processes, or living with the fact that your application is going to leak memory like crazy
- It isn't supported or recommended by Microsoft
- Office wasn't designed with server-side security considerations in mind

See the following for additional details:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757